# What command can I use to preview merges while EXCLUDING commits with no changes

Tags: git

I would like to see a list of commits that would be merged into the mainline, but skip those commits that introduce changes already in the mainline (that would case git merge to skip).

Say I have `master` branch, and I want to merge `development`. And I use `git log master..development` to preview what commits I'll be merging.

The number of commits between the two is pretty high i.e 500. To reduce my workload I want to eliminate those commits whose changes are already in `master`. (could happen say if 200 of the commits in development were squash merged into master at some point)

what is the git command to view only the commits that will introduce changes?

Comment: Not an answer, but 500 commits sounds like a massive number of commits.  This, combined with expecting to merge in many commits which are functionally identical to the target branch suggest that you might want to fix your branching strategy.

Comment: Agree with Tim B, you should not cherry-pick/squash merge that many commits. Also, how does listing the commits reduce the workload? Either way you have to do `git merge development` and resolve any conflicts? Any commits that do not introduce any changes will not cause any merge conflicts either.

Comment: I understand your concerns but please understand that for big teams the numbers I'm throwing out here are really not that big. Especially where you have 50 fixes and features coming in daily. Either way I believe providing an answer to this question would help someone even if they are only dealing with 10 commits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the git command to view only the commits that will introduce changes?

There isn't one.  You may be able to *approximate* one (see below), but this is a dangerous road.

Fundamentally, the issue here is that after a squash-merge, you *should* **stop using** all the commits that were squash-merged, i.e., kill off the squash-merged branch entirely.  If you keep using the branch, it's up to you to figure out how to deal with that: Git is not going to help you out.

Remember that `git merge` works by:

- finding the merge base;
- in effect, running two `git diff`s, from the merge base to each branch tip;
- combining the resulting changes; and
- committing the result, recording *both* parents, so that the *next* merge uses a different merge base.

Modifying this with `git merge --squash` keeps all of the above *except* that the last step—the final commit—(1) is disabled as if by `--no-commit` and (2) is made *without* recording both parents, so that the *next* merge will have the same merge base.

A future re-merge therefore counts on the "combining" step managing to see any previously-squash-merged changes as being duplicated, and de-duplicating them.  This tends to work with small amounts of changes, and fail with large amounts.

With that in mind, let's look at a case example.  We'll start with this history:

```
...--o--*--A------B   <-- mainline
         \
          C--D--E--F   <-- feature
```

If we were to do a normal merge of `feature` into `mainline` at this point, we'd get:

```
...--o--*--A------B--G   <-- mainline
         \          /
          C--D--E--F   <-- feature
```

where the merge base was commit `*` and the two branch tips were commits `B` and `F`.  Git combined changes-since-`*`-at-`B` with changes-since-`*`-at-`F` to make `G`.

We can now continue developing `feature` by adding more commits.  A future `git merge` uses commit `F`, not commit `*`, as the merge base.

But if we instead use `git merge --squash`, we get this graph:

```
...--o--*--A------B--G   <-- mainline
         \
          C--D--E--F   <-- feature
```

There's nothing to remember that commit `F` was the state `feature` had when we made commit`G`.  So, in the future, when we have:

```
...--o--*--A------B--G-----K   <-- mainline
         \
          C--D--E--F--H--I--J   <-- feature
```

there is no way to know that the "interesting" commits are `H-I-J` (and of course `K` itself).

You *should* kill off branch `feature` when squash-merging, so that you now have:

```
...--o--*--A------B--G------K   <-- mainline
                      \
                       H--I--J   <-- feature2
```

Now it's clear that the "interesting" commits are `H-I-J` (and `K`).  Alternatively, don't use squash-merge: just do a regular merge, so that you have:

```
...--o--*--A------B--G-----K   <-- mainline
         \          /
          C--D--E--F--H--I--J   <-- feature
```

and again it's clear—well, it is to Git at least; you can use `feature..mainline` to find this with help from Git—that the interesting commits are `H-I-J` (and `K`).

#### Approximating, if you insist

Now, you can, if you wish, scan the entire set of commits `C` through `J`—those on `mainline..feature` after your earlier squash-merge—and try doing a `git cherry-pick` of each such commit.<sup>1</sup>  In **some** (easy) cases, Git will discover that cherry-picking `C` has no effect.  The same will hold for `D`, `E`, and `F`.  Cherry-picking `G`, `H`, and `I` *will* have an effect.

This concept breaks down in a lot of real, actual cases.  For instance, suppose commit `D` is a *revert* of commit `C`.  In this case, cherry-picking `C` onto a new branch sprouting from commit `K` *will* have an effect.  Cherry-picking `D` atop it will *undo* the effect since `D` is a revert.  You can build a tool that handles this special case, but then what if the revert of `C` is `E` rather than `D`?

The general case calls for merges to be recorded as merges.  Hence the general rule is that `git merge --squash` "kills off" a branch.  All of its commits should be discarded: they've been *replaced* by the squash-merge; that's the new-and-improved form of *all* of the squash-merged commits; they should never be seen again.

---

<sup>1</sup>You can do this on a new branch, or on a detached HEAD, for the purpose of testing whether the cherry-pick actually picks anything.